# Column Not Found 1054 Unknown column

Tags: symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I'm running on a deadline tomorrow can anybody help me? Here is my error. I checked my database several times and still I'm getting an error:

```
10/29/15 15:46:54,366 [1780] ERROR filter.ExceptionCatcherFilter -
Uncaught Exception: exception 'DaoException' with message
'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
'o.period_from' in 'field list'. Failing Query: "SELECT o.id AS o__id,
o.name AS o__name, o.hours_per_day AS o__hours_per_day, o.start_time
AS o__start_time, o.period_from AS o__period_from, o.period_to AS
o__period_to, o.end_time AS o__end_time FROM ohrm_work_shift o ORDER
BY o.name ASC"' in
C:\xampp\htdocs\ucmedhris4dev\symfony\plugins\orangehrmAdminPlugin\lib\dao\WorkShiftDao.php:34
```

Here is my base class

```
abstract class BaseWorkShift extends sfDoctrineRecord
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('ohrm_work_shift');
        $this->hasColumn('id', 'integer', null, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'primary' => true,
             'autoincrement' => true,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('name', 'string', 260, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'notnull' => true,
             'length' => 260,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('hours_per_day as hoursPerDay', 'decimal', 4, array(
             'type' => 'decimal',
             'notnull' => true,
             'scale' => false,
             'length' => 4,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('start_time', 'time', null, array(
             'type' => 'time',
             'notnull' => true,
             ));
         $this->hasColumn('period_from', 'string', null, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'notnull' => true,

             ));

          $this->hasColumn('period_to', 'string', null, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'notnull' => true,

             ));
        $this->hasColumn('end_time', 'time', null, array(
             'type' => 'time',
             'notnull' => true,
             ));


    }

    public function getPeriodFrom(){ 
        return parent::_get('period_from'); 
    } 

    public function getPeriodTo(){ 
        return parent::_get('period_to'); 
    } 

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->hasMany('EmployeeWorkShift', array(
             'local' => 'id',
             'foreign' => 'work_shift_id'));
    }
}
```

Comment: You checked the database... what was the result? Because I'm 100% sure the column really does not exist.

Comment: How Can I Close This Question? Ive already solved my problem thanks bro. Ive created a database column for this lately but it was gone maybe its because of the console command I generated from symfony task command line when I put the database column manually its now running back smoothly ^_^ thanks for the help bro you saved me from my deadline.